# A formula must choose between three choices depending on a if/then statement

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am creating a formula that checks to see if a number is either above 1.25, below 1.25 or equals 1.25. Depending on which one it matches, a different formula will be applied.

I understand​ that you can do:

```
=IF(B7 >= 1.25,"yes","no")
```

But it doesn't give me a third option, so I cannot make a third formula.

Answer (score 2):

Nest them.

```
=IF(B7 > 1.25,"higher",IF(B7 < 1.25,"lower","equal"))
```

Spelled out:

- if B7 is more than my value, show "higher"
- else

  - if B7 is less than my value, show "lower"
  - else show "equal"

You can replace the display of strings with other formulae, like so:

```
=IF(B7 > 1.25,AVERAGE(C1:C7),IF(B7 < 1.25,B10 + 2,B7))
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Next question, can I use a formula instead of a string in the nest? I tried:

=IF(B7 > 1.25,"higher",IF(B7 < 1.25,"B10 + 2","equal"))

But all it does is show B10 + 2 as a string


Ha ha figured it out... I just remove the "" how silly of me. Thanks again!

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark. This acts as a signpost for people in the future who have the same question. More information in the [Help Center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).